# How to replace part of audio in a video using the command line?

Tags: command-line, audio, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

Part of a recorded audio contains sensitive information. I want to remove that information while keeping the video and rest of the audio intact. Ideally using command line and being able to exactly specify the beginning and end.

Comment: What do you want to do, exactly? Your question title makes me think you want to [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15795112/1109017) to your video, but your question content makes me think you want to mute a segment of your audio.

Comment: Part of recorded audio contains sensitive information. I want to remove that information while keeping the video and rest of the audio intact. I'll put this into the question itself as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segment, replace audio of portion that you want, concat the pieces back together.

https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368151/adding-silent-audio-to-mov-in-ffmpeg

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files

I do not know if this will provide a flawless execution but it is how I would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @dstob's answer, I noticed that nobody had suggested any code.  Here's what I did<sup>1</sup>:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c copy -t 00:01:30 seg1.mkv # segment the clip at time=90 seconds
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c copy -ss 00:01:30 seg2.mkv # obtain the remainder of the clip
ffmpeg -i seg1.mkv -i in.wav -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 new-seg.mkv # replace audio from the first 90 seconds of the original clip using in.wav
ffmpeg -i new-seg.mkv -i seg2.mkv -filter_complex "concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -vn final-out.mkv # concatenate them back together; v=1 and a=1 are telling ffmpeg that both files have video and audio; n=2 tells ffmpeg that you are concatenating two files
# rm seg1.mkv seg2.mkv new-seg.mkv # clean up
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that I tried to do minimum re-encoding and options (to make it as general as possible for people's ease of use).  One will have to follow the links provided by @dstob to find out more about flags/options.